# Could process running only on one processor have threads running on other processors?

Tags: windows, multithreading, synchronization, multiprocessing

Is it possible, in multiprocessor environment (PC) that one windows process is configured to run only on one processor (affinity mask = 1 or `SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(),1)`), but its thread are spawned on other processors?

(Question came from discussion started in one company, regarding using synchronization objects (Events, Mutexes, Semaphores) and WinAPIs, like `WaitForSignleObject`, etc, especially `SignalObjectAndWait` for which MSDN states

> "Note that the "signal" and "wait" are not guaranteed to be performed
>   as an atomic operation. Threads executing on other processors can
>   observe the signaled state of the first object before the thread
>   calling SignalObjectAndWait begins its wait on the second object"

Does it mean that for single processor it's guaranteed to be atomic?

P.S. Is there any differences for Windows Context Switching that there are multiple processors or single processor with more real cores?

*P.P.S. Please be patient with this question if I didn't use exact and concrete terms - this are is still not very good known for me.*

Comment: "affinity mask = 00" does little to help document your question.

Comment: ok, let it be 1, I'll update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The set of processor cores a thread can run on is the intersection of the process affinity mask and the thread affinity mask.

To get the behavior you describe, one would set the thread affinity mask for the main thread, and not mess with the process mask.

For your followup questions: If it isn't atomic, it isn't atomic.  There are additional guarantees for threads sharing a core, because preemption follows certain rules, but they are very complex, since relative priority and dynamic priority are important factors in thread scheduling.  Because of the complexity, it is best to use proper synchronization.

Notably, race conditions between threads of equal priority certainly still exist on a single core (or single core restricted) system, but they are far less frequent and therefore far more difficult to find and debug.